# RecyclerView drag & drop via itemTouchHelper bahaving strange when dragging fast

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I've been following guide from this link ["Drag and Swipe with RecyclerView - by IPaulPro"](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.auoxhinl4) and i am having few problems on some situations.

So, i basically did all that he explained + i added a TextView in item that represents the position of an item in RecyclerView, something like this:
[image]

Everything appears nice except when i start "sling shooting" items fast, then i have two problems:

1. It happens to have a duplicate of numbers.
   [image]

   Also what i did was using `notifyAdapterSetChanged()` in the
   `onItemClear()` method - it fixed it in a way, but caused
   `IllegalStateException`, which catched - would lead to
   `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.
2. Ocasionally,when swiped too fast, item gets in the "background". This can only be seen if items are not the same size.
   [image]

I will paste my whole adapter code below, there must be a flaw somewhere in it.

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
AndroidEntityQuestionResult androidEntityQuestionResult;
ArrayList<AndroidEntityAnswer> list = new ArrayList<>();
ORDLayoutManagerQuestion ord;
ScreenDimensionsConstants sdc;


public OrderingRecycleAdapter(Context context, AndroidEntityQuestionResult androidEntityQuestionResult, ORDLayoutManagerQuestion ord) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = androidEntityQuestionResult.getAndroidEntityQuestion().getEntityAnswer();
    this.androidEntityQuestionResult = androidEntityQuestionResult;
    this.ord = ord;
    sdc = new ScreenDimensionsConstants(context);
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_ordering_rv, parent, false);
    final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = new OrderingViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof OrderingViewHolder) {

        ((OrderingViewHolder) holder).answerText.setText(list.get(position).getAnswer().getANSWER_TEXT());
        int currentPosition = position + 1;
        ((OrderingViewHolder) holder).position.setText("#" + currentPosition);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, i + 1);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(fromPosition);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {

}

@Override
public void onStartDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        ord.getItemTouchHelper().startDrag(viewHolder);
}

class OrderingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
    private TextView answerText;
    private ImageView pin;
    private TextView position;

    public OrderingViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        answerText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderingAnswer);
        answerText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, sdc.getHeight() / 40);

        pin = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ordering_pin);
        pin.getLayoutParams().width = sdc.getHeight() / 15;
        pin.getLayoutParams().height = sdc.getHeight() / 15;

        pin.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) ==
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    OrderingRecycleAdapter.this.onStartDrag(OrderingViewHolder.this);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        position = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.answer_position);
        position.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, sdc.getHeight() / 40);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected() {
        itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_item_background_ice_blue);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClear() {
        itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_item_background_white);
        int currentPosition = getLayoutPosition() + 1;
        position.setText("#" + currentPosition);
       //notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

**BONUS QUESTION**

Is there any tutorial or any info related to drag and drop between 2 RecyclerViews?

I know that there is a question on SO, but with no answer, i may be luckier here.

Comment: I am also using the code from the link you referred above and i was also in trouble when i was doing swaping too much fast but i solved this by overring 
onSelectedChanged in the class extended from ItemTouchHelper.Callback .

Comment: With what code did you override it? I used the code from the https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/paulburke/android/itemtouchhelperdemo/helper/SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.java

Comment: Would you like to post my code and use it ? or you want a fix ? *i don't want to see "i didn't want code, i want a fix"* that's why i'm asking.

Comment: Can you please share the Screendimensionsconstants and ORDLayoutManagerQuestion classes? ORDLayoutManagerQuestion is of particular interest because of the itemtouchhelper. And maybe can you try to shift your on touch listener on the onbindviewholder.

Answer (score 3):

Change your onitemmove method

```
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, i + 1);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(fromPosition);
    return true;
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, i + 1);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, i - 1);
        }
    }
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Not working, you have to drag it position by position this way and that is not what i want to achieve.

Comment: no you dont want to drag it position by position, just try this code and tell me

Comment: My mistake, its not moving position by position - it can be moved through the list but it gets back on its fromPosition when released and notifyItemRangeChanged forces it to dynamically change value of items that are being hovered, looks kinda bad.

Comment: try only adding notifyitemmoved and remove 2nd and 3rd notify call from my answer

Comment: Having one notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition) will only notify item that is being dragged, there has to be a notify on the item that gets to the fromPosition (in my case notifyItemChanged(fromPosition). What notifyItemMoved you want me to add? When adding notifyItemMoved(toPosition, fromPosition) with the first notify, it wont change anything when released, everything will go back to its place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103503/discussion-between-ankitagrawal-and-sekula1991).

Comment: Can you please edit your current answer with that updated code, because i don't understand what you want me to do? Thanks.

Comment: Like i told you on chat and previously in comments - it is not working.

Comment: This is brilliant! When we move fast, android does not emit changes one-by-one, but  it can skip spans. How could I not predicted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like your onItemMove() does not account for all the changes.
When something moves for more than one item (lets say between A & B), you are are swapping all the items between the two.
However you report changes only to A & B and not to the rest of the elements in between.

I suggest you write a swap method that reports all the changes:

```
public boolean swapItems(int fromPosition, int toPosition){
    Collections.swap(list, fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    notifyItemMoved(toPosition, fromPosition);
    // And maybe also notifyItemChanged() as the item changes due to the shift
    notifyItemChanged(fromPosition);
    notifyItemChanged(toPosition);
}
```

Call this function instead of Collections.swap() and remove the rest of the notify code.

Comment: Sadly, it's not working, when dragging one item with this code, all items change their values dinamically while dragging which looks really odd, and when released, an item gets back into its place.

Comment: By the way, isn't it correct to do like i previously did - only A and B item change their position, those in between stay where they are? Maybe i should notify those items around toPosition (+1 -1) because they sometimes interfere and i just cant find the reason why it happens (With some if statements if toPosition == list.size(); )

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, Since I can't see the correct answer posting the answer here. Just add `notifyItemRangeChanged(fromPosition,toPosition)` before return true.

```
notifyItemChanged(fromPosition);
notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
notifyItemRangeChanged(fromPosition,toPosition)
```